# How to Create a SQL query to display a counter of messages read

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am very new to Sql and I hope someone can help, I have a Table called Project_Table(pjtID) and another Table called Snag_Table(foreign key sngProject_ID), then i have a FeedBack_Table (foreign Key fdb_Snag_ID).
What i need is that when a user clicks on a snag they can write a message and when they return to the list of snags it must not show that they have  any messages pending for them, but the user that the Snag was assigned to logs in and sees there is a message for them. How i handle whether it has been read or not is handled somewhere else. I have structured a SQL query that displays the list of snags and the counter.

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN fdbRead = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ReadCount,
        sngCreatedBy,sngAssignedToEmail,sngProject_ID,
        u1.useFullName as Createdname,
        sngCreatedBy,sngID,sngTitle,u2.useFullName as AssignedName,
        sngAssignedTo,sngStatusName,sngDescription,sngStartDate,
        sngDueDate,sngCreatedBy 
FROM Snag_Table 
    INNER JOIN User_Table u1 ON Snag_Table.sngCreatedBy = u1.useID 
    Left JOIN User_Table u2 ON Snag_Table.sngAssignedTo = u2.useID 
    LEFT JOIN FeedBack_Table ON Snag_Table.sngID = fdb_Snag_ID 
WHERE sngProject_ID = 10 
AND sngIsActive = 1 
GROUP BY sngCreatedBy,sngAssignedToEmail,sngProject_ID,
        u1.useFullName,Snag_Table.sngID,Snag_Table.sngTitle,
        u2.useFullName,sngAssignedTo,sngStatusName,sngDescription,
        sngStartDate,sngDueDate  
ORDER BY sngID DESC
```

What i am getting is the counter regardless of who is logged in and who created the feedback.
So i tried adding some logic into the query to display counter based on who is logged in so i added after the where fdbCreatedBy != 17

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN fdbRead = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ReadCount,
        sngCreatedBy,sngAssignedToEmail,sngProject_ID,
        u1.useFullName as Createdname,sngCreatedBy,
        sngID,sngTitle,u2.useFullName as AssignedName,
        sngAssignedTo,sngStatusName,sngDescription,sngStartDate,
        sngDueDate,sngCreatedBy 
FROM Snag_Table 
    INNER JOIN User_Table u1 ON Snag_Table.sngCreatedBy = u1.useID 
    Left JOIN User_Table u2 ON Snag_Table.sngAssignedTo = u2.useID 
    LEFT JOIN FeedBack_Table ON Snag_Table.sngID = fdb_Snag_ID 
WHERE *fdbCreatedBy != 17* 
AND sngProject_ID = 10 
AND sngIsActive = 1 
GROUP BY sngCreatedBy,sngAssignedToEmail,sngProject_ID,
        u1.useFullName,Snag_Table.sngID,Snag_Table.sngTitle,
        u2.useFullName,sngAssignedTo,sngStatusName,sngDescription,
        sngStartDate,sngDueDate  
ORDER BY sngID DESC
```

Now the counter does work as desired but only if there are already feedbacks attached to the snag, but if i create a new snag an refresh the list it doesnt show the snag.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: If you format you code so it is readable, we may bother to stop by and look at it. You may also have more chance of understanding what you wrote in a few weeks when you come to modify it

Comment: Qualify the columns, i.e. specify the table for each column - so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Please, if possible, re-create your database sample at http://sqlfiddle.com and add this to your post.

Comment: Thanks all for providing feedback. Ill take all your suggestions into account next time. Sorry if i caused any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

Remove the condition from where

```
WHERE *fdbCreatedBy != 17*
```

and add that condition in your case statement

```
Count(CASE   WHEN (fdbread = 2 and  [fdbcreatedby] != 17 )THEN 1  ELSE NULL   END) AS readcount
```

Comment: Thank you Anson that helped solve my problem . Very much appreciated .